# How to catch click event on NSImageView as subview in NSTableRowView?

Tags: cocoa, events, nsimageview, nstablerowview

In NSTableView I have NSTableRowView and in this row there is some NSImageView subview. 
Question: how to track click event on this image?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create `NSImageView` subclass to handle mouse events. But `NSTableView` does not allow handling `-[NSImageView mouseUp:]` and other mouse messages. (I think this is related to how a table handles selection).

In this situation I had to use a borderless "Bevel - Switch" button to handle clicks.